# Looping through a javaScript object's array with angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

So I'm absolutely new to writing any type of code, I'm trying to build a simple website using AngularJS and I'm having a problem with looping through a controller's object array through a directive template. My goal is to output each array string into a separate list item element in the template,
for example in the controller I have

```
    $scope.items = [
    {
     list: ["1", "2", "3"],
     name: "whatever"
    },
    {
     list: ["4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],
     name: "whatever2"
    }]
```

in the directive template I have written something like this

```
    <h1>{{ directive.name }}</h1>
    <ul id= "items"></ul>
    <script>
            for (var i = 0; i < directive.list[].length; i++) {
                  document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = 
                   "<li>{{" + directive.list[i] + "}}</li>";
            };
    </script>
```

the name object retrieves correctly in `index.html` using the template but list object will not output the array, gave it my best shot, tried troubleshooting to get it right and I can't seem to figure it out, need help :( hope I'm being clear enough, this is my first attempt at creating anything and still trying to get familiar with all the jargon.

Comment: I think you need two repeats...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shot:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
   <h1>{{ i.name }}</h1>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in i.list">{{i}} </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And the description:

Basically you want to loop through all the items in your array `<div ng-repeat..` then for each of those items you want to create the `<ul>`

Comment: Thanks, it's just that i've written a seperate directive file and linked it to a template to write an HTML tag , so that i can move the objects into a JSON file from the controller and upload online once done. trying to experiment with different things, maybe getting ahead of myself

Answer (score 1):

It's simple -- replace your `<script>` with this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}
        <ul id="items">
            <li ng-repeat="list_item in item.list">{{ list_item }}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```