# Populate <dl> list from array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I am using angularJS and have a javascript array of objects, each object has

```
Count
ID
Subject
```

I would like to use this array to populate a  with these values:

```
                            <dl>
                                <dt>Count</dt>
                                <dd>Subject</dd>
                                  <!--all objects should appear as above-->  
                            </dl>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you tried ng-repeat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through a javaScript object's array with angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494297/looping-through-a-javascript-objects-array-with-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.yourArray = [
    {"Count": "something1", "ID":  "something2", "Subject":  "something3"},
    {"Count": "something1", "ID":  "something2", "Subject":  "something3"},
    {"Count": "something1", "ID":  "something2", "Subject":  "something3"},
    {"Count": "something1", "ID":  "something2", "Subject":  "something3"}
]; // On the controller

<dl ng-repeat="item in yourArray">
    <dt>{{item.Count}}</dt>
    <dd>{{item.Subject}}</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<dl ng-repeat="myDataItem in myDataArr">
  <dt>{{ myDataItem.Count }}</dt>
  <dd>{{ myDataItem.Subject }}</dd>
</dl>
```